# Responsive layout with 3 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design the homepage of my blog with the following layout:

[image: layout]

"container" is a responsive div that changes its width with the width of the screen. The yellow blocks are previews of the articles (image and title). I want the first four blocks to be bigger and display in a 2 column style. Starting with block #5, they need to be smaller and split into three columns.

Now the first four are easy, I just make blocks #1 and #3 align to the left, and blocks #2 and #4 to the right. But how do I style the 3-column part? Please keep in mind that those are not actually columns and the code goes like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>block1</div>
  <div>block2</div>
  <div>block3</div>
  <div>block4</div>
  <div>block5</div>
  <div>block6</div>
  <div>block7</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can prefer this http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Check out Modest Grid and customise your own grid system http://www.modestgrid.com/custom-download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `flexbox` position, e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbzojM

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /* align boxes on the left when they don't fill an entire row */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#container > div {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#container div {
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

#container div:nth-child(n + 5) {
  width: -webkit-calc(33.33% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(33.33% - 20px);
  width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
}
```

Note: for some browser you may need to specify a different syntax, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

---

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! One question... how do I add a 20px padding between the divs? 

I'm thinking:

1st and 3rd blocks: 10px right padding;
2nd and 4th: 10px left padding;
block 5: 10px right;
block 6: 10px left and right;
block 7: 10px left?

Comment: Once again, thank you so much, works perfect. One last thing: If I add block #8, it comes out centered (under block 6). Is it possible to make it float to the left (under block 5)?

Comment: please specify this also in the question, since later answers may need to know this in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid system. This is how the Twitter Bootstrap grid system works for extra small and medium sized devices. You can define how wide the column should be at different screen widths by adding the necessary class references eg. 'col-xs-12'.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /*-webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;*/

}
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
.container {
  width: 970px;
}
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-md-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-md-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-md-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-md-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-md-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-md-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-md-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-md-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
}
.block {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><div class="block">Block1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><div class="block">Block2</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><div class="block">Block3</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><div class="block">Block4</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><div class="block">Block5</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><div class="block">Block6</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><div class="block">Block7</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with Bootstrap, why not just use the Bootstrap grid? No extra CSS is needed.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-6">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-6">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-6">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">    </div>
```

http://bootply.com/qujivH7vXb